# How to concatenate string which has double quotes in it (JMeter)

Tags: string, jmeter, concatenation, beanshell

I have a situation where I need to concatenate two strings 1 and 2.

```
Str1: {"CodeName":"service:batch","data":{"prId":${TestId},"filters":[{
Str2: "tallId":
```

To look like:

```
{"CodeName":"service:batch","data":{"prId":${TestId},"filters":[{"tallId":
```

Have tried:

```
Str1 = Str1 + "\"tallId\":";
```

Comment: What is the error? i can concatenate both string successfully.

Comment: I am using JMeter's beanshell to do it. there is no error its just doesn't give me the exact result.  At the end it adds twice like this:  },"filters":[{"tallId":"tallId":

Comment: can you share your beanshell?

Comment: mainString is declared in the Test Plan:
`mainString = {"CodeName":"service:batch","data":{"prId":${TestId},"filters":[{`  

`String Str1 = vars.get("mainString");`  

So,
`Str1 = Str1 + "\"teamId\":";`  
`vars.put("mainString", Str1);`

Answer (score 1):

1. Building JSON using string concatenation is not the best option
2. Inlining [JMeter Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Script body a **very** bad practice
3. Since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31) [it is recommended to use JSR223 Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting in JMeter

So I would recommend reconsidering your approach using Groovy language as it has [built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) so you should be able to create a "good" JSON Object from JMeter Variables without having to worry about quotation marks, commas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in your beanshell script area:

```
String Str1 = vars.get("mainString");
String Str2 = "\"teamId\":";
String Str3 = Str1 + Str2;
vars.put("NewString", Str3);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ararar. But it still repeats the teamId twice e.g. "filters":[{"teamId":"teamId":

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your beanshell because even with your code in the comments above i can still have it done successfully.

Comment: Thank you @ararar. I will work on it and see what is wrong here.

Comment: Where do you get the Str2 value ("teamId":) from?

Comment: well, right now I just need to concatenate these strings.. there is no value in Str2.

Comment: well just debug your beanshell and make sure you have only one concatenation statement coz it seems like you have 2 and thats why its concatenated twice, if not try using JSR223 instead of beanshell.

Comment: Thanks @ararar. seems there was some issue in my beanshell. Working good now!